# How can I make a line after a heading with font awesome icon in the middle?

Tags: html, css

Am trying to do the same as the photo shows but I don't really know how to do that

[image]

So I should be able to have that line with any fontawesome icon in the middle.

Here my initial markup:

```
<h1>Welcome</h1>

h1 {
    font-size: 25pt;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 300;
}
h1:after {
    content: '\f209';
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    display: block;
}
```

[Here my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Wosley_Alarico/jx4dv11g/1/)

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By giving your `h1` a `border-bottom` and positioning your `:after` icon absolute in the center inside it. Also apply a white background to make sure the line gets interrupted.

```
h1 {
    font-size: 25pt;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

h1:after {
    content: '\f209';
    position: absolute;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    background-color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

[Update fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jx4dv11g/2/)

Comment: 100% useful answer

Answer (score 4):

Well... the accepted answer works fine, but it involves set widths, and will need to be rewritten to cater for longer text in the heading. The following works regardless of width of text (it does, however, involve a little bit more HTML):

https://jsfiddle.net/jx4dv11g/3/

```css
h1 {
    font-size: 25pt;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

.headericon {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}
.headericon i {
  display: block;
  margin-top: -25%;
  background: white;
  transform: translate(-50%,0);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<h1>Welcome to this page<br><span class="headericon"><i class="fa fa-hand-peace-o"></i></span></h1>
```

Comment: A good solution as well, upvoted. I didn't choose the responsive one because I didn't think OP would change the "welcome" text anytime soon.

Comment: Nah, probably not, but it might be helpful for others trying to do similar things.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest you to use following `HTML` structure for this:

```
<h1 class="styled-heading">
  Welcome to HTML and CSS

  <span class="fa fa-hand-peace-o"></span>
</h1>
```

Apply a class on `h1` and use pseudo elements `:before` and `:after` to draw lines around icon.

This will allow you to have one time generic styling for all similar places in your web page. If you wants to use different icon in some other heading then all you need is just change the font awesome icon in that header.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
.styled-heading {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25pt;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.styled-heading .fa {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.styled-heading:before,
.styled-heading:after {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  margin-left: 30px;
  width: 999px;
  height: 1px;
  content: '';
  bottom: 12px;
  left: 50%;
}
.styled-heading:after {
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-left: 0;
  right: 50%;
  left: auto;
}

.orange {
  background: orange;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<h1 class="styled-heading">
  Welcome to HTML and CSS
  <span class="fa fa-hand-peace-o"></span>
</h1>

<div class="orange">
  <h1 class="styled-heading">
    Welcome To HTML and CSS.
    <span class="fa fa-home"></span>
  </h1>
</div>
<div class="blue">
  <h1 class="styled-heading">
    Welcome To HTML and CSS.
    <span class="fa fa-globe"></span>
  </h1>
</div>
<div class="green">
  <h1 class="styled-heading">
    Welcome To HTML and CSS.
    <span class="fa fa-power-off"></span>
  </h1>
</div>
```